# Testing PHP parse errors with phpunit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I need to test how our error logger works in various scenarios. One such scenario are parse errors. Here's an example:

```
public function testParseErrorLogsAnError()
{
    $this->assertCount(0, $this->log_handler->getRecords());

    try {
        eval('<?php not good');
        $this->fail('Code above should throw a parse error');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(\ParseError::class, $e);
    }

    $this->assertCount(1, $this->log_handler->getRecords());
}
```

Problem is that phpunit always exists with an exception, and never enters `catch` block. How to disable or orverride phpunit's exception handler, so we can test our own?

Comment: An exception being thrown is a PHP7 feature of eval. Are you using PHP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer, I'm assuming you're using PHP 7. In PHP 5, Parse Errors cannot be caught and will always terminate your PHP process.

In PHP 7, you *can* catch Parse Errors using a *try/catch* statement (contrary to what the other answer says). However, PHP 7's `ParseError` class extends the `Error` class, not `Exception` (see also the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.parseerror.php)). So `catch (\Exception $e)` will not work, but any of these should:

```
catch (\ParseError $e) { ...
catch (\Error $e) { ...
catch (\Throwable $e) { ...
```

---

Alternatively, use the `@expectedException` annotation als already suggested by @DevDonkey:

```
/**
 * @expectedException ParseError
 */
public function testParseErrorLogsAnError()
{
    eval('<?php not good');
}
```